# Deploying Asp.Net 2.0 AJAX Extsions in BIN folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0

My web server does not have the framework installed and they are telling me to use the DLLs in bin folder.. is there any difference (performance, security etc) between deploying it by server installation and through bin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in output.

If you are installing the AJAX extensions in the server dlls will go and sit in `GAC`.

If dll is in application's bin folder then is called `local assemblies`
If dll is in [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(VS.71).aspx) then is called local assemblies:`global assemblies`.